# Creacion de Vista SQL con 2 Tablas, diferentes registros

Tags: sql

Quiero crear una vista con 2 tablas, pero con campos diferentes, tengo las tablas

```
Estudiantes (Nombre, Apellido),
Asistencias (Status)
```

esta es la sentencia que he usado pero no me funciona

```
CREATE VIEW V_ASISTENCIA_PROM
AS SELECT nombre, apellido
FROM ESTUDIANTES
As SELECT status 
FROM ASISTENCIAS;
```

Comment: ¿Qué salida esperas obtener? Te recomiendo lograr primero una consulta que te devuelva el resultado deseado y luego preocuparte de crear la vista.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Eso no va a crear ninguna vista ya que hay 2 selects distintos. Que esperabas obtener?

Answer (score 0):

--esta podria ser una solucion no se si te sirva, a mi parecer el motivo por que no te lo muestra esta en que usas una palabra reservada ademas que estas usando dos from diferentes cuando puedes usar solamente uno.

```
CREATE DATABASE PRACTICA
USE PRACTICA 

CREATE TABLE Estudiantes (Nombre VARCHAR (10), Apellido VARCHAR (10)); 
CREATE TABLE Asistencias (Statu VARCHAR (10)); 

insert into Estudiantes values ('carlos','pancho');
insert into Asistencias values ('aprobado');

CREATE VIEW V_ASISTENCIA_PROM
AS SELECT nombre, apellido, statu FROM ESTUDIANTES, Asistencias;

select* from V_ASISTENCIA_PROM
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la Tabla de Asistencias y estudiante tenga **Id** del estudiante como método de relación como llaves entre tablas, mencionando que dices que ya tienes las tablas te podría servir lo siguiente:

1- Consulta General

```
SELECT 
A."nombre", 
A."apellido", 
B."status"
FROM "ESTUDIANTES" A
INNER JOIN "ASISTENCIAS" B ON A."IdEstudiante"=B."IdEstuAsis"
```

Comprobando que dicha consulta te retorne algo antes de pensar en hacer la vista.

2- Crear la vista de acuerdo al resultado que te devuelve la consulta.

```
CREATE VIEW "V_ASISTENCIA_PROM"
AS SELECT 
A."nombre", 
A."apellido", 
B."status"
FROM "ESTUDIANTES" A
INNER JOIN "ASISTENCIAS" B ON A."IdEstudiante"=B."IdEstuAsis";
```

3- Ver la información que te arroja ya la vista creada.

```
select * from "V_ASISTENCIA_PROM"
```

Saludos.